# Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context: Date dateHolidayHandler.isdaybusinessday(Date, Boolean)

Tags: datetime, salesforce, apex

Hi guys this is one of the method from my class when i calling from test class i am getting error related to static method cannot be referenced from a non static context

```
public static date adddayswithholidays(date indate,integer noofdays,boolean reverse){ 
    //Create a set for the holiday dates
    set<date> holidayset = new set<date>();
    boolean bstop = false;
    
    //Get the holiday dates
    If (!bholidayrun){
        holidaylist=[select activitydate from holiday];
        bholidayrun =true;
    }
    
    //Setup the holiday set
    If (holidaylist !=null){
        for (holiday h:holidaylist){
            holidayset.add(h.activitydate);
        }
    } 
    for(Integer i=0;i < noofdays;i++){
            //If this date is in the holiday list
            //Add a day. Repeat until not a holiday.
            bstop =false;
            If(holidayset !=null){
                while(bstop ==false){
                    if(holidayset.contains(indate)){
                        //Add a day
                        indate = indate.adddays(1);
                    }else{
                        bstop = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Add the next day to the indate
            If(reverse){
                indate =indate.adddays(-1);
            }else{
                indate =indate.adddays(1);
            }
            
            Datetime dt = datetime.newInstance(indate.year(), indate.month(),indate.day());
            String weekday = dt.format('E'); 
            
            if (weekday == 'Sat'){
                system.debug('found a saturday' + indate);
                If(reverse){
                    indate =indate.adddays(-1);
                }else{
                    indate =indate.adddays(2);
                }
            }
            if (weekday =='Sun'){
                system.debug('found a sunday' + indate);
                If(reverse){
                    indate =indate.adddays(-2);
                }else{
                    indate =indate.adddays(1);
                }
            }
            
            //Check for holidays again before sending back
            bstop =false;
            If(holidayset !=null){
                while(bstop ==false){
                    if(holidayset.contains(indate)){
                        //Add a day
                        If(reverse){
                            indate =indate.adddays(-1);
                        }else{
                            indate =indate.adddays(1);
                        }
                        
                    }else{
                        bstop = true;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    return indate;
}
```

//this is the test class where how i got error

//problem1:whenever i call i am getting error Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context

```
@isTest static void UnitTest1(){
```

dateHolidayHandler d=new dateHolidayHandler();
Boolean bholidayrun=true;

```
    date indate=Date.today().addDays(1);
    date td1=Date.today().addDays(-2);
    Holiday h=new Holiday();
    h.name='test';
    h.ActivityDate=date.today();
    insert h;
    system.assertEquals(system.today(), h.ActivityDate);
    d.adddayswithholidays(indate, 1, true);
    d.isdaybusinessday(td1, true);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you to stop doing that

```apex
dateHolidayHandler d=new dateHolidayHandler();
// ...
d.adddayswithholidays(indate, 1, true);
d.isdaybusinessday(td1, true);
```

Your method is static so it doesn't need an instance, it doesn't need "new".

Call it as `DateHolidayHandler.adddayswithholidays(indate, 1, true);`